# Load page into div when all images are fully loaded after a load for a loading screen

Tags: jquery

If I click a button the content of a DIV first should be replaced by load_page.php and then
through another page by the second load when the second page is done loading all the images.

The second page contains a lot of images and only should be displayed when completely loaded.

```
$('.query_button').on('click', function (e) {
    $("#content").load('./pages/load_page.php');
    $("#content").load('./pages/second_page.php');
});
```

But instead the load_page gets replaced immediately and you can see how the second page still
loads all images.

**EDIT**
I noticed another strange event. Sometimes load_page.php loads after second_page.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your second_page.php the images begins to load, this is because of the way the browser works, when it see an image tag, it will load the image.
I will suggest you look into the preload images and connect it with jQuery.

Take a look at this simple preload: http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/preload-images-with-jquery-preload-plugin/

instead of:

```
$("#content").load('./pages/second_page.php');
```

you might want to go for

```
$.get('./pages/second_page.php', function(data){
// preload images before publishing to content
$.preload( '/img/space.gif',
  '/img/avatar.jpg'
);
$("#content").html(data);
});
```

EDIT: Regarding your issue with load_page loading second is because .load() is an async function, you can't tell which is finished first, to fix this use this code, it will start by loading first_page.php, and when done loading it will begin to load second_page.php

```
$("#content").load("first_page.php", function(){
$.get('./pages/second_page.php', function(data){
    // preload images before publishing to content
    $.preload( '/img/space.gif',
      '/img/avatar.jpg'
    );
    $("#content").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it sadly didn't solve my problem. I want to display load_page.php so long until second_page.php is complety ready.

Comment: are the images you want to preload random or always the same? do you know the images to preload on the original page? if so use the preload feature i linked to before setting the $("#content").html(data);

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't load the "load_page.php" file: simply include it in your template and hide it, then show it as soon as you start loading "second_page.php".

Something like:

```
var content = $('#content');
var loading = $('#loading-content');
$('.query_button').on('click', function (e) {
    loading.show();
    content.hide().load('./pages/second_page.php', function(){
        loading.hide();
        content.show();
    });
});
```